# RabbitMQ C++ Client consumer_cancel_notify

Tags: rabbitmq

Following the guidelines [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-cancel.html) I'm able to set the "consumer_cancel_notify" property for my client connection, but when the Queue is deleted the client still isn't noticing. I'm guessing that I probably have to override some method or set a callback somewhere, but after digging through the source code I'm lost as to where I'd do this. Does anybody offhand know where I'd listen for this notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's how I got it to work:

1. When creating the Queue (i.e. "declaring" the Queue), add a callback for the "AMQP_CANCEL" messages.
2. Inside AMQPQueue::sendConsumeCommand(), inside the while(1) loop where the code checks for the different *frame.payload.method.id*s, add a check for the AMQP_BASIC_CANCEL_METHOD, e.g.

   ```
       if (frame.payload.method.id == AMQP_BASIC_CANCEL_METHOD){
           cout << "AMQP_BASIC_CANCEL_METHOD received" << endl;
           if ( events.find(AMQP_CANCEL) != events.end() ) {
              (*events[AMQP_CANCEL])(pmessage);
           }
           continue;
       }
   ```

That's it.

For my purposes I wanted to redeclare the Queue if it got deleted so that I could keep consuming messages, so inside my callback I just redeclared the queue, set up the bindings, added events, set the consumer tag, and consumed.